# Trouble sending File from React frontend with Fetch to Express 4 API

Tags: reactjs, express, fetch-api

I am attempting to send an image file from my React frontend to my express API:

```
fetch('http://localhost:4000/upload/', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: this.state.picture[0],
})
```

The file looks correct in the chrome console when I log it:

```
File {name: "31-614x614.jpg", lastModified: 1553111550472, lastModifiedDate: Wed Mar 20 2019 12:52:30 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 95101, …}
```

However when I try to log the file in the request on my backend, I either get undefined or empty request objects depending on how I set it up.

I've tried using multer, busboy, and express-fileupload as recommended in similar stack overflow questions, but have the same issues.

Here's my router:

```
const Router = require('express').Router();
const imgController = require('./controllers/imgController');

Router.get('/images/', imgController.getImages);
Router.post('/upload/', imgController.postImage);

module.exports = Router;
```

And the controller where I'm simply trying to see the file being sent:

```
exports.postImage = (req, res) => {
  console.log("IN POST IMAGE")
  console.log(req.body)
  console.log(req.files)
}
```

I do get into the controller, but the request never contains the file.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried building a [formData](https://github.com/github/fetch#file-upload) element and sending that?

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')

var data = new FormData()
data.append('file', input.files[0])
data.append('user', 'hubot')

fetch('/avatars', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
})
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried it, but no dice :( I believe it's something to do with my server setup being able to read the request.

Comment: You'll need to use a `middleware` parser to handle `multipart/form-data` requests: https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Comment: As mentioned in my post I tried both of the above packages to no avail. express-fileupload looked super simple to use too.

Comment: @David then show us your code with one of the packages

Comment: I got it working using the form data you suggested and multer, the issue was I needed to have the Router use the correct Multer middleware function, rather than the express app. Thanks!